# Changing text color depending on background

Tags: css

I have a background that animates (it is not a solid color, but actually a canvas animation), but will at each "end" have two specific colors. I would like some text that sits on top of the animation to change color such that when it sits on top of the lighter of the two it is black, and on top of the darker of the two it is white.

To illustrate, see simplified snippet below with simpler animated background (it's not too far from black, but quite far from white)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  function draw(timestamp) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#BDDAE4";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    var x = (timestamp / 50) % (c.width + 40) - 40;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#79B3C9";
    ctx.fillRect(x, 40, 40, c.height - 40);

    ctx.fillRect(0, c.height - 40, c.width, c.height);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
div p {
  font-size: 2em;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="c" height="120" width="100"></canvas>
  <p>TEXT</p>
</div>
<p>(Scroll on the text to see)</p>
```

I figure that if there is a way, it will include mix-blend-mode and/or filter.

Comment: You mean the top half should be black and bottom half of text should be white? Or that when the background of the element is light blue, the text is black and when it is dark blue, the text is white? If it is the latter, would it not be ok to change the text color during the animation itself?

Comment: The latter. On top of the light blue, text should be black, on top of dark blue it should be white.

Comment: In that case would it not be ok to animate the text color also during background animation?

Comment: You'll need top make the changing text color part of the same animation that changes the background color for this to be full-proof. How are you making the background change color? Presumably just with Keyframes?

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/s80w0xuq/) is what I had in mind.

Comment: The background is not just a single color. It is a canvas animation that depends on scroll position and time. This is why I think it needs to be done with mix-blend-mode, because then it doesn't matter how the background comes about

Comment: Would it be possible to include the canvas animation also in the demo? It might be easier to work on a solution.

Comment: I've updated the code to include a much simpler animation